# connecting ftp server using python

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

I try to connect to an ftp server in my phone using python code and I get an error.

**Code**

```
import ftplib
server = ftplib.FTP()
server.connect('192.168.135.101', 5556)
server.login('svgn','123456')
print (server.dir())
```

**Error**

> C:\Python27\python.exe
>   C:/Users/alisivgin/PycharmProjects/untitled2/deneme2.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/alisivgin/PycharmProjects/untitled2/deneme2.py", line 3, in
>   
>       server.connect('192.168.135.101', 5556)   File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 132, in connect
>       self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in
>   create_connection
>       raise err socket.error: [Errno 10061] Hedef makine etkin olarak reddetti�inden ba�lant� kurulamad
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to connect using any FTP client? Because the error indicates, the connection is not possible (the FTP server is not running?)

Answer (score 11):

## Try below code, even i have faced same problems before.

```
import ftplib
server = ftplib.FTP()
server.connect('192.168.135.101', 5556)
server.login('svgn','123456')
# You don't have to print this, because this command itself prints dir contents 
server.dir()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try below code

```
from ftplib import FTP


global ftp
ftp = FTP('192.168.135.101', user='svgn', passwd='123456')
print "connected to FTP"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the connection towards the given IP (192.168.135.101) with port (5556) .Please try Telnet to the port

> telnet 192.168.135.101 5556

from the command prompt(for windows users ) or from the Linux console .

If connectivity has some issue you can check with the network admin/your firewall rules to make the connection through.

If connectivity is fine then check FTP server is available in the remote server  (192.168.135.101) in case of RHEL you can check

> service vsftpd status

If it has FTP service(vsftpd (pid XXXX) is running response from the above command ) then check the FTP configuration .

Else (vsftpd: unrecognized service response from the above command) install the FTP server ) and try again for FTP.
After all these troubleshooting, you should be able to access the remote server via FTP.